# How to customize user location pin (Xamarin Forms Google Map)

Tags: ios, forms, dictionary, xamarin, pins

All is in the title, I just want to customise the user location pin with the package Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps on IOS.

I've already tried this but it doesn't work at all and the user location pin is always the default.

```
Map_Pharmacy.Pins.Add(new Pin
{
    Type = PinType.Place,
    Label = pharmacy.Name,
    Position = pharmacyPosition,
    Tag = pharmacy.Id,
    Icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBundle("UserLocation"),
});
```

Note that I use the Asset Catalog. The same code for other pins works well. Only user location pin seem impossible to customise...

Comment: By default you can't change the default user location pin, but you can do this by custom render class for both iOS and Android or you can use this plugin it support the custom pin https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Comment: I already use this plugin, the code above used it ...